# How to configure a lambda service

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Let's say I'm deploying an AWS lambda app via CF. How can I pass any configuration parameters to it?

For example I want to pass the one of the generated bucket references, so it can be used in the code.

Comment: Hi there... 
Is the code of your function node.js ?

Comment: Does it matter? I expected some generic interface for passing down configuration.

Comment: it does matter for what I was about to propose, yes... : )  If it IS node.js you can inline the code in the CF template, so you can add your `"Ref"` there, using the CF join function

Comment: It's python - I believe you can inline that too. Although I thought that's a terrible hack.

Comment: haha - hacks are still solutions  ;)
on the other hand, I'm not sure you can inline python -- according to the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html) anyway... (i'm referring to the `ZipFile` property)

Comment: Have a look at serverless.com - it adds variables (and other cool stuff) to the AWS lambda experience.

Comment: To clarify, are you attempting to pass references from CloudFormation into a Lambda function being used as an [AWS Lambda-backed Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html), or are you asking for a Lambda function deployed via CloudFormation, and being used for an entirely different, unexplained purpose (e.g., responding to DynamoDB stream events, or whatever), to use references from the CloudFormation stack within your Lambda code?

Answer (score 0):

this are the valid cloudformation parameters for a lambda function

```
{
   "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Function",
   "Properties" : {
   "Code" : Code,
   "Description" : String,
   "Handler" : String,
   "MemorySize" : Integer,
   "Role" : String,
   "Runtime" : String,
   "Timeout" : Integer
 }
}
```

If you want to pass a parameter defined by you in your template you can specify on the parameters section and use the ref and join function 
for more information see :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html

Comment: This does not solve the issue as described. The parameters you describe are for the lambda creation, not execution parameters. Check the example from the question.